# Trying to REMOVE data from a COLUMN

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get rid of all the CPAC_FR as showed below

```
Facility Response   CPAC_FR Transfer Call        2016-03-07         1
Facility Response   CPAC_FR Fulfillment-Email   2016-03-04  4
Facility Response   CPAC_FR Fulfillment-Email   2016-03-10  1
Facility Response   CPAC_FR Fulfillment-Email   2016-03-17  2
Facility Response   CPAC_FR Fulfillment-Email   2016-03-21  2
```

Here's my code. I'm still learning how to write query so I keep getting stuck on things.

```
SELECT  SR_AREA, INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, CAST(CREATED AS DATE) AS DATEADD
      , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM    S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)          
WHERE   (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '3-1-2016')  
AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016'))  
AND  [SR_AREA] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, SR_AREA,  CAST(CREATED AS DATE) 
ORDER BY SR_AREA,INS_PRODUCT,RESOLUTION_CD DESC
```

I'm leaning more into adding a `DELETE FROM .. WHERE ..`

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Since you are still learning perhaps it is not too late to convince you to stop littering your queries with that NOLOCK hint. Unless you like results that are mostly correct and mostly accurate most of the time. If you don't like occasionally recieveing duplicate and/or missing rows you should not be using that hint. There are a whole list of other pitfalls using NOLOCK that most people don't know about.  http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1):

When working with a single table - Once you have your `SELECT` statement returning only the data you want to actually delete you can then replace the `'SELECT` with `DELETE` and remove the clauses `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. In your example you would end up with this:

```
DELETE
FROM    S_SRV_REQ
WHERE   (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '3-1-2016') 
AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016')) 
AND  [SR_AREA] IS NOT NULL
```

Side Notes:

- Take FK constraints into consideration, the update might fail because of a constraint or might cascade delete constraining records depending on the FK constraint setting.
- It is also advisable to always test DELETE statements in a non production setting first to ensure they behave as expected.
- Finally it is also never a bad idea to let a co-worker review a DELETE statement before execution in a production environment.

---

**Edit**

I am assuming by this `Trying to delete data from a row` you mean `Trying to delete data from a` **table**. You cannot delete data from a row although you can update a value in a row to `NULL` if that column allows for nullable data/value. If that is the case update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Delete will not work with a group by
Start with a select and be sure those are the rows you want to delete

```
SELECT  SR_AREA, INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, CAST(CREATED AS DATE) AS DATEADD
FROM    S_SRV_REQ        
WHERE   (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '3-1-2016')  
AND     (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016'))  
AND     [SR_AREA] IS NOT NULL
```

then just change the select .... line to delete

```
DELETE 
FROM    S_SRV_REQ        
WHERE   (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '3-1-2016')  
AND     (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016'))  
AND     [SR_AREA] IS NOT NUL
```